# Removed Boot Entry of Ubuntu 20.04 from Bios

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

**Hello**
I was having a system with Dualboot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 but I decided to unistall Ubuntu so I deleted its partition from Windows and as usual the grub was present in its place and i tried changing Windows boot path and also tried rebuilding mbr of disk but unluckly they did't worked for me. So instead of messing with Windows I booted to UEFI Configuration and then deleted 2 boot entries of Ubuntu which were above Windows and now I only one OS in my computer left. So did I performed the correct method ? Will it cause any problem in future ? Thankyou.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the risk of stating the obvious, if it works, it works. You removed an OS and its corresponding boot entries, and your computer works as expected. There's no reason to expect any trouble from that in the future, any later OS installation should set up its own configuration as needed.